# How can I dynamically make folder with today's date?

Tags: php, date, mkdir

Is it possible and if it is, how can I create automatically folders that have the names of the current date? I read that `mkdir()` will make me do the folders but how exactly to set the name of these folders so when I get information from some link the folder where i have to save this `.txt` file to be created with for example - name: 'May-21-2014' (the current date).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first input of `mkdir()` is [the name](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php). Just put the string of the date into the value you pass it:

```
$name=date("l");
makdir($name//etc)
```

would result in a folder called *Monday*.

Just format the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) as you want it.

I would suggest folders to be yyyymmdd - eg `20140522` for today, it makes them sort nicely in ascending date order in a normal directory browser.

This would be:

```
$name=date('Ymd');
```

when you make the folder name.

Comment: Make sure your server's timezone is correct too! You don't want your US hosted website to be run in the UK at about, say, 1am for the server to create a folder for yesterday because, according to the server, it is still the day before!

Comment: @BigChris Indeed. Totally agree, make sure the time setting/offset you use is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir(strftime("%B %d %Y, %X %Z",mktime(20,0,0,12,31,98)),0777,true);
```

Answer (score -1):

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

  `mkdir(date('Y/m/d'), 0777, true);`

Comment: Really? You want folder names with a `/` character in them? Interesting.